# Implementing Drop on Picturebox on Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2017, oledragdrop

I seem unable to make it so that I can drop a file from the desktop to a PictureBox on a Form.

I went through all the docs I could find, but anyways the cursor always stays a stop sign.

What I did was:

Set the Form's "AllowDrop" to True.

In my code I have

```
Private Sub pb0A_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles pb0A.DragOver
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
End Sub

Private Sub pb0A_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles pb0A.DragEnter
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
End Sub
```

In the docs I read that I should set the PictureBox'es property "AllowDrop" to True, but using Framework 4.5.2, I don't have this property.

I'm not running VS as an admin.

What else might be the problem here?

Comment: For some reason other than "by design" they dont expose the `AllowDrop` property in the Properties Pane.  Set it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason Microsoft has intentionally hidden the [**`PictureBox.AllowDrop` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.allowdrop(v=vs.110).aspx). It isn't visible in the designer nor listed by IntelliSense, however it does exist so you can still set it through code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.AllowDrop = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, it isn't recognized in IntelliSense. Can you add this to your answer? Had I known it earlier (I did try that, but when Intellisense didn't show it to me, I thought it wouldn't work), I'd have tried that.

Comment: @tmighty : I know. They've hidden it completely (for reasons unknown), but it works. :)

Comment: Can you add this info to your answer for others? I mean the fact that Intellisense doesn't show it?

Comment: Thank you!! Also for the great help!

Comment: @tmighty : Not that it was very much to help with, but sure, no problem :). Good luck!

Comment: Intellisense doesnt see it because MS adds the `EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)` attribute to hide it.  They have indicated this is "by design" but not *why*. @tmighty